# SQL 'WHERE NOT some condition' not excluding condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

`WHERE NOT some condition` is not excluding that condition from my query.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    n.timestamp AS tm
FROM 
    (SELECT timestamp, uid 
     FROM nodes 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT timestamp, uid FROM ways) n
WHERE 
    NOT n.uid = '12055' OR NOT n.uid = '2132512';
```

Currently this query returns in 3579897 rows.

Reference:

All timestamps from dataset:

```
SELECT n.timestamp as tm
FROM (SELECT timestamp FROM nodes UNION ALL SELECT timestamp FROM ways) n;
```

returns 3579897 rows.

Timestamps from condition:

```
SELECT n.timestamp as tm
FROM (SELECT timestamp, uid FROM nodes UNION ALL SELECT timestamp, uid FROM ways) n
WHERE n.uid='12055' OR n.uid='2132512'
```

returns 2254097 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WHERE NOT n.uid = '12055' AND NOT n.uid = '2132512';
```

Your version will return all rows -- one or the other conditions will (almost) always be true.  Okay, it will filter out `NULL` values of `n.uid`.

Or more eloquently as:

```
WHERE n.uid NOT IN ('12055', '2132512');
```

If the `uid` is a number (which I expect), then you should drop the single quotes:

```
WHERE n.uid NOT IN (12055, 2132512);
```

Comment: Yes, the uid is a number.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that it's a [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) here, that makes `NOT (n.uid = 12055 OR n.uid = 2132512)` (what the OP had in mind I believe) equal to `NOT n.uid = 12055 AND NOT n.uid = 2132512` and not equal to `NOT n.uid = 12055 OR NOT n.uid = 2132512`.